Switched to Gas from Induction, hate it, is it the range?
I know this borders on too subjective but.... I had a nice Induction stove top (36" Bosch) and wall ovens, then I moved to an older house with Gas.  Worse, with attic and walls that make it very difficult (and ugly with conduit) to put in an induction range, so I am living with gas.
I hate it.  It's definitely better than radiant electric, but...
The house was freshly remodeled so it was a new range, a GE JGSS66SEL5SS which appears to be at the low end of gas ranges, though not the bottom.  Burners max out at 15k BTU, oven is 16k.
The oven is a one problem -- it pre-heats very quickly but the temperatures vary wildly from center to edges, like parchment paper in the center nice and white and brown to almost black on the edges. So it's basically half-size with me using only the center. It also has "steam clean" that does nothing (literally - the water does not even evaporate), no self-clean mode.
The other issue is that the burners are quick to react (of course) but weak. Boiling water is very slow, and in a big pot (e.g. I use for steaming things) on full it can barely get a continuous boil going.
The center griddle is nice, though also heats unevenly, hot in the center, cool on edges despite an oval burner.
Here is my question -- are better (i.e. pricier) ranges actually better, or is this just how gas is? If I look at something like a high end LG gas range (for example), am I likely to be more satisfied?  They clearly have faster burners (22k vs 15k) but is uneven heat in the oven just how gas works, or will a better range have better air flow and more even heat?
Or was I just spoiled with electric ovens and induction cook tops?
How much actual difference is there in such issues between 30" ranges (and no, I really do not have space for 36" or to switch to cooktop + wall ovens, it's an old house with many limitations).
Linwood

I've cooked on friend's gas stoves, and although all of the burners look  the same, there might be one or two that can crank out more flame than the others, so you don't have to wait 30 mins for a pot of water to boil for pasta.  If you have to, you might be able to get a single countertop induction unit, as many are 15amps, but I've never used them for boiling water and other really high heat uses.

The kitchen work area is small, so not really interested in a separate induction hob (plus it would be away from the vent/hood.  on this range the two front burners are the same power (15k), so I am sure another range could be higher power.  It's more the oven that bothers me, extremely uneven heat inside.  If you put the same thing on the sides vs center one would be raw while the other well done.  One friend said "that's just gas" but she had an electric oven so...

Cast iron pans might help with the uneven cooking... or something else with a heavy bottom

Have somebody measure the gas pressure at the appliance and verify it is within spec. Also, newer higher-pressure gas systems have a indoor regulator at the point of use, that has to be properly installed and adjusted. You are on natural gas, not LP? Appliance modifications are needed for LP.

It's Natural Gas.  When I moved in I had a gas appliance repair guy come and check everything, whether he tested pressure I do not know, but it said everything was set up properly.

How slow is ‘very slow’ for boiling water? At typical gas burner efficiencies (40% of the heat goes into the cookware if you’re lucky), you’re looking at probably 4-5 minutes to get 1 liter of water from 20 degrees Celsius to 100 degrees Celsius using a 15k BTU burner running on full. That’s not particularly slow, but it’s not all that amazingly fast if you’re used a good induction stove (I’ve seen ones that can get the same 1l of water from 20 to 100 in 90 seconds).

It's that you switched from a five thousand dollar induction stove, to gas for five hundred w/o convection.

btw. I learned only recently that apparently gas stoves are a health risk

@Mazura - yes, I understand, what I really did was switch from a house in Florida to one in North Carolina, and like many transplants it had side effects.  Boiling:  I'll time it, you have me curious.

@mb21 They can be, but with good fume extraction the risk is minimized. The problem is there are a lot of gas stoves in kitchens with poor extraction or no extraction at all.

@AustinHemmelgarn I put 1 liter of water at 69F  (20C) in a 3qt AllClad sauce pan and on the highest setting and hottest burner it took 5 min 9 sec to get tiny bubbles that could reach the top and 6 min 32 seconds to get what I would call a full boil, with center surface water temp about 208F (97C).  That burner is rated at 15k BTU.  So similar range of time, depends on how you determine it has reached 100C, as the bottom reaches it much quicker than the top.  But right range.  This pan is a good match, the bigger issue is a big pan with lots of water barely sustains a boil.

@mb21 The fact is cooking itself is a health risk, releasing particulates and fumes into the air. You don't want to breathe over a frying pan. In all cases, what you need is good outside exhaust, which you very often have to pay to have put in these days. In commercial kitchens, code makes you do this, regardless of the fuel source.

Health/pollution seems a bit out of scope to my question.

Looks like 15k BTU is typical. Spot-checking a few current models, KitchenAid (similar to or possibly identical to what I currently have) has a 20k large burner and some semi-random others that I picked GE 15k, Frigidaire 18k.

I don't want to be a pest, but as someone who switched to induction from gas and loves it, what's stopping you from replacing the gas line with conduit? I used the old black pipe as a guide for where to put the new circuit in my old home.

The kitchen is freshly remodeled with new tile walls and cabinets.  The only way to get power to it is tear that up, or run conduit all along the brick wall outside and come in behind the stove.  Neither is attractive (in either appearance or cost).


the temperatures vary wildly from center to edges

Yes, this is a common problem with gas ranges.
In my experience, people frequently choose an incorrect pan size for the burner. I prefer to use a pan such that the flames don't hit the outer edge of the pan, but that they make a ring that's maybe 2/3 of the radius between the center and edge. That way, you have the least uneven heating, because the pan bottom gets less hot with distance from the flames, and also the pan middle cools down less than the pan edges (which both have more area to radiate away the heat, and are not heated from two opposite sides within a given diameter).
Range design can improve the problem with two approaches. First, the engineers can choose the burner's physical size and flame holes angle to control the size of the flames ring. So they can ideally choose a power output that's sufficient to heat the pan well when placed as described above. Second, they can make a two-ring burner, such that, for a wide pan, you have heating in more area than from a single ring.
Also, when it comes to evenness of heating: you can control that by choosing your pan material. There is a tradeoff: a pan that's slow to conduct will have a more even heating pattern, but will also react more sluggishly to changes in burner output. But frequently, a food is highly sensitive to either reaction times or to even heating, but not so much both at once, so you can use your pan choices to get whatever you need most for a given dish. Especially after you've been "confined" to induction-suitable materials only, it might be a good idea to explore how other pans will handle on the new stove.

Also, to address the "subjective" part: it's indeed normal that people learn cooking by doing it always on the same range, and when they switch to a different range, that handles subtly differently, their skill is "out of whack" and they end up hating the new range. We have had questions here from people who switched from gas and induction and hated it with passion! So, while your observations about the objective differences make sense and it's absolutely a good thing to consider other models, you should also give yourself time to adjust. Things which used to "just work" by instinct might need a more conscious control now, not because the new range is worse, but because it's different. This effect is unavoidable, but it will disappear with time, as you build an implicit mental model of how the new range handles in different situation, and start using it instinctively again. This is a component which will be always present, independently of the range quality.

Thank you, this is helpful.  I have been in the house cooking with it about 5 months, so I have given it a decent if not long try. The description of design for the oven burners may allow me to at least guess if a potential replacement will be different.  Consumer Reports also has some baking ratings that may help, I was just reading through them. But I think it's time to go physically look at potential replacements.

You quote a complaint about the gas oven and then talk about problems with a gas burner.  This seems to leave the most important question open, do gas ovens always heat unevenly or would it be possible to replace it with a more even gas oven.  I suspect that other gas ovens are better or we'd hear more complaints, but not sure that's past where Linwood has already thought.  My experience is that gas burners can easily boil water, so I think we can all agree that better burners are possible.

@mdfst13 you're right! I overlooked that the OP is referring to the oven in that part, as it is also a common problem with stove burners. But I am somewhat confused now, because they have also marked the answer as the accepted one.

@rumtscho: OP complains about both. They also noted that the center girdle heated unevenly. Thus your advice on pans are definitely on the mark.

@mdfst13 gas ovens with a convection fan have less temperature variation - most ovens I've seen in the last 10+ years have a convection fan.

@Luciano Flesh that out a bit and it sounds like an answer, look for a gas oven with a convection fan for more even heating.

I marked it as the better answer because it confirmed gas is bad about evenness especially in the oven, but more because it described some alternative oven designs (that should be visible if I go shopping) that might help with the even distribution of heat.  Sadly most stores won't let me cook a pound of bacon in their oven to test it.

@Linwood sorry for the misunderstanding - when I wrote that, I had stove burners in mind, not oven burners, because I overlooked the "oven" reference in your paragraph about unevenness. I have no idea if this applies to oven burners, as I have never used a gas oven (or even seen one in real life)! If you thought I wrote about oven burners, I can understand it if you remove the accept mark and give it to the other answer.

If you are using cast iron pans suitable for induction, they are about the worst possible choice for gas. You need pans with a thick base to spread the heat from the burner, but low heat capacity so as maximize the rate at which heat reaches the food. This means aluminium, or (usually expensive) stainless steel with a well-attached aluminium or aluminium-filled base. (Cheap pans with badly attached aluminium bases heat up unevenly, and you get burned patches).

that final paragraph talking about building the mental model for how this new stove is - what a nice, succinct way to put it. i'll be thinking about (and perhaps linking to) that paragraph in time

Gas can be very good, you just need the right equipment. Low-end gas ranges have teeny burners and take ages to cook anything, better equipment has much bigger burners. I have a 5 burner cooktop with 2 double ring wok burners, and I have no problem boiling a big pot of water quickly. So, better equipment will give you a better result. Keep in mind more expensive brands do not necessarily give you better burners, you can buy a very expensive, swanky brand that's still pathetic. You need to look at the amount of heat in kW or BTUs that the burners crank out, not the name on the front.
One good option may be to buy used, depending on what's in your area you may snap up a bargain - sometimes people get rid of perfectly good stuff.

Not sure if this is out of bounds here but then - which brands would provide a better oven.  It's pretty easy to tell the burners by BTU, but the evenness of temperature in the oven is a different issue.

My general understanding is that electric ovens are better in a number of ways than gas - when I redid my kitchen (> 20 years ago) I switched the cooktop from electric to gas and later replaced the single electric wall oven with a double with self-cleaning and convection. But while I had to do a lot of work for the bigger oven (brick wall), both gas and electric connections were easy because kitchen right above utility room. Most people don't have it that easy.

Yes.  My issue is space and power. An inaccessible attic, built on a slab, running anything but the 15a/120v outlet to where the stove is requires major work, or extreme ugly (conduit outside, down the wall and thru the wall behind the stove), or removal of a lot of ceiling and wall (including wall tile and cabinets). The cost of the range, even a good one, is minor compared to the cost and ugliness of getting higher amperage electricity to that area.

I don't know where you are so cannot advise on brands @Linwood. I would suggest trying to get the one you have fixed first before buying new. It may work fine after a bit of a cleaning and servicing.

It doesn't really need cleaning as it was brand new and I have not messed it up. It functions, as in all the controls work (except "steam clean" and maybe that's just a gimmick).  I could pay someone to come out and look at the oven, but the real problem is that it is uneven, not so much at the wrong temperature. Is that even something one can "fix"?  Or is it a design in how air flows in the oven?  I'm in the US, in North Carolina.

@Linwood No idea what's available on the US market, but from an European perspective it feels to me that 15A/120V should be enough for an electric oven (combined with a gas cooktop). Around here, ovens are somewhere around 2 kW, which is fairly close to what your 15A outlet could deliver, so this should be possible in theory (but as I said, no idea if it's also available in practice). Gas ovens are the worst; gas cooktops are not-ideal-but-bearable (the worst thing being all that waste heat that makes cooking on warmer days really unpleasant).

@TooTea "around here" (I'm also in Europe), real ovens are certainly not 120V, they are frequently 360V, having an extra line to supply them. 2 kW is typical for small ovens, maybe even toaster ovens, and they don't work as well as the large ones which have a large thermal mass and would need endless preheating at mere 2kW.

@rumtscho I've never seen a three-phase oven; three-phase supplies are common on ranges where one phase (230V) supplies the oven and each of the other two phases feed one half of the cooktop. Combined gas-electric ranges with just an ordinary 230V plug for the oven are readily available, and all the standalone ovens I've had also had just a 230V plug. Yes, grown-up ovens can easily take around 3 kW with all the elements used simultaneously, but how often do you need that? Those 1.8 kW available for a hypothetical US 120V oven should be enough in most situations.

@rumtscho As a random data point, my current oven (Gorenje BPS747A32XG) takes roughly 1000W for top heat, 1100W for bottom heat, and some 2100W in convection mode. So roughly 2 kW is enough to make it happy in either top+bottom or convection mode.
